# angularjs 400 bad request during http post request

Tags: angularjs, post, request, django-rest-framework

I'm in the middle of constructing a single page web application, with an Django Rest Framework API backend. I'm having issue sending off registration forms. I think there's a problem with the way the dates are formatted.
Here's what the controller looks like:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('CityWits')
    .controller('standardController', standardController);

standardController.$inject = ['UserService','$location', '$rootScope', 'FlashService'];
function standardController(UserService, $location, $rootScope, FlashService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.standard = standard;

    function standard() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;

        var str = [];
        for(var p in vm.user){
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(vm.user[p]));
        }
        str = str.join("&");

        UserService.CreateStandard(vm.user)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                    $location.path('/sign-in');
                } else {
                    alert(response.message)
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
    }

    function fixDate(date){


    }
}
```

})();

The Post requests:

```
 function CreateStandard(user) {
        console.log(user)
        return $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/standard', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    }
```

The json object being sent from the form:

```
Object
```

date_of_birth
:
Fri Aug 06 1993 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
first_name
:
"David"
gender
:
"M"
last_name
:
"Galloway"
user
:
Object
email
:
"dcgallo93@gmail.com"
password
:
"*******"
**proto**
:
Object
**proto**
:
Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the HTTP Header "Content Type" to JSON if you want to post as JSON string.

Otherwise, the data needs to be in form of *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, which means something like this: ***parameter=value&also=another***

This is highlighted [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) in the DRF doc:

> Note: When developing client applications always remember to make sure
>   you're setting the Content-Type header when sending data in an HTTP
>   request.
>
> If you don't set the content type, most clients will default to using
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', which may not be what you wanted.
>
> As an example, if you are sending json encoded data using jQuery with
>   the .ajax() method, you should make sure to include the contentType:
>   'application/json' setting.

Frankly, JSON is clearer to see, so what I would do is:

```
function CreateStandard(user) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/standard', 
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }).then(...);
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350583/django-and-angular-communication-failure) question please? I have effected these suggestions, but still get the error...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to send the `user` object:

```
function CreateStandard(user) {
    console.log(user)
    return $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/standard', JSON.stringify(user))
                .then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
}
```

Comment: Tried it, its still sending back 400 bad request

Comment: Would you kindly take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350583/django-and-angular-communication-failure) question please? I have effected these suggestions, but still get the error...

Comment: @DavidGalloway Have you found a fix for this bad request issue?